# Can't access array members

Tags: php, arrays

I can't figure this out.  I've create a simple class that returns an array of arrays. Here is the class contructor...

```
class BlogComments {
public $commentArray=array();
public $blogId;

function  __construct($inId) {
    if(!empty($inId)) {
        $this->blogId=$inId;
        $sql="select id,name,url,comment,email from blog_comment where blog_id=$inId";
        $link2=GetConnection();
        $query=mysql_query($sql,$link2) or die("Invalid blog id:".mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $this->commentArray=array(
                "id"=>$row['id'],
                "name"=>$row['name'],
                "url"=>$row['url'],
                "email"=>$row['email'],
                "comment"=>$row['comment']
            );
        }
        mysql_close($link2);
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to access each member of the array via a loop. It's entering the loop but the values returned are empty.  I've verified that data is being written into the array. Here's my code...

```
include "include/commentclass.php";
$comments = new BlogComments($post->id);
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    echo "<h4>".$comment->commentArray['name']."</h4>
        <a href=\"".$comment->commentArray['url']."\">".$comment->commentArray['url']."</a>
        <p>".$comment->commentArray['comment']."</p>";
}
```

Basically it returns empty tags. I've also verified that $post->id holds a valid value. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,
B

Comment: you cannot iterate on the object Reference. As netcoder says in his answer you should implement Traversable in order to do that. Or just implement a method in your class that will give you the $commentArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$comments = new BlogComments($post->id);
foreach ($comments->commentArray as $comment) {
    echo "<h4>".$comment['name']."</h4>
        <a href=\"".$comment['url']."\">".$comment['url']."</a>
        <p>".$comment['comment']."</p>";
}
```

The `new` keyword returns a single object. Unless your object (`BlogComments`) implements `Traversable`, `foreach` will act on the public properties `commentArray` and `blogId`, and not on the `commentArray` contents.

You could also have your class implement an `Iterator` interface.

Comment: Thanks netcoder, I'm getting values now but it's weird.  It is returning...<h4>5</h4><a href=5><p>5</p> then <h4>t</h4><a href=t><p>t</p>.  the comment id is 5 and the name for that id starts with t. I can't figure out why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some mistakes, the first is the one netcoder pointed out: you are using the object as an array without implementing an `Iterator` interface. The second is that you are assigning directly the result array to `$this->commentArray`. You should append the result to the array this way: `$this->commentArray[] = array(`

Comment: You're both right. I needed to append the result to the array as you stated and using netcoders code I was able to get it both to work.  Thanks to both of you!

Comment: +1 @Minkiele: Good call, I didn\'t see the missing `[]` there.